# regex first 3 letters thats in a certain way to something

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of links that look like this below

```
/en
/en/admin
/en/admin/content
/en/admin/content/paragraphs
/en/admin/structure
/en/admin/structure/block
/en/admin/structure/contact
```

I want to replace occurrences of /en to something like /en-gb (/en-$country) and the word gb is in a variable $country.

The end result would be for example

```
/en-gb
/en-gb/admin
/eb-gb/admin/content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better to use preg_replace here because we are looking at the beginning of the string here.

```
$string = preg_replace("/^(\/?)([a-z]{2})/", "$1$2-".$country, $string);
```

Comment: Why so many groups? Use `preg_replace('~^/?[a-z]{2}~', '$0-'.$country, $string)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with str_replace easily:

```
$string = str_replace('/en/', '/en-'.$country.'/', $string);
```

And here, just in case the shortest regex version:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\/[a-z]{2}/', '$0-'.$country, $string);
```

Explanation:

```
^        look at the begin of the string
\/       look for an / (\ is for escaping)
[a-z]{2} look for two characters a-z
```

Comment: but the word en could be ch, cn or any 2 letter word

Comment: Then replace `en` with a variable.

Comment: static or from a variable?

Comment: static not a variable

Comment: You'll be replacing this pattern not only in the beginning but also within the string.

Comment: i guess the url design is from himself.. so /en/ will not occur twice

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). To match only the pattern in the beginning, use the following regex:

```
^\/(en)\/
```

If you want to match all two character strings (with wordlike characters), you can use:

```
^\/(\w{2})\/
```

The two characters are then in the first matching group `$1`.

Comment: but the word en can be ch, cn or any 2 letter word

Answer (score 0):

`$orig` can be a string or an array of strings. This will replace it anywhere in the string, not just at the beginning:

```
$lang = "en";
$country = "gb";

$orig = str_replace("$lang", "$lang-$country", $orig);
```

If you need to replace only at the beginning:

```
$orig = preg_replace("#^/$lang#", "/$lang-$country", $orig);
```